Jira Mail Handler
I am trying to automate support tickets in Jira. There are 5 different projects and therefore 5 different clients who will send support requests. I was only allowed to use one email, which is Support. I have it configured so that any client can send a ticket, and Jira interprets it using a keyword and places it in its respective project.
The issue is that the created project's ticket is saved with my user and not with the client who created the ticket. Does anyone know how to solve this?

If I remove the default reporter, this will result in another problem, which is that now the clients send the tickets, but Jira will not save them.

Any ideas on how I can keep the default reporter field empty so that tickets are not saved under my user? And how can I get the tickets created if I leave it empty?
